# Conditionally filling null values with left join in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a joined table using two tables, `series` and `events`. The structure for `series` table looks like following:

| series_id | step | timestamp | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 2 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| a | 4000 | 2018-08-14T15:30:40-0400 | 4 | 2 |
| a | 4001 | 2018-08-14T15:30:45-0400 | 7 | 9 |
| a | 4002 | 2018-08-14T15:30:50-0400 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| b | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 3 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| b | 3000 | 2018-08-14T15:33:00-0400 | 23 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The structure for `events` table looks like the following:

| series_id | step | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4001 | 2018-08-14T15:30:00-0400 | o |
| a | 9001 | 2018-08-14T15:30:00-0400 | w |
| b | 3000 | 2018-08-14T15:30:00-0400 | o |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to create a table which has all the rows from `series` table, but from the `events` table it picks up the event value in the upcoming step (for example, event should be `o` for all steps < 4001 and series_id a). How can I do that in pyspark? My final table should look like this:

| series_id | step | timestamp | x | y | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 2 | 3 | o |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| a | 4000 | 2018-08-14T15:30:40-0400 | 4 | 2 | o |
| a | 4001 | 2018-08-14T15:30:45-0400 | 7 | 9 | o |
| a | 4002 | 2018-08-14T15:30:50-0400 | 1 | 1 | w |
| a | 4003 | 2018-08-14T15:30:55-0400 | 2 | 9 | w |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| b | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 3 | 2 | o |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| b | 3000 | 2018-08-14T15:33:00-0400 | 23 | 1 | o |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

Or, how can I fill the `null` values conditionally in the events column when I do a left outer join on the `events` and `series` table?

| series_id | step | timestamp | x | y | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 2 | 3 | a |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| a | 4000 | 2018-08-14T15:30:40-0400 | 4 | 2 | a |
| a | 4001 | 2018-08-14T15:30:45-0400 | 7 | 9 | o |
| a | 4002 | 2018-08-14T15:30:50-0400 | 1 | 1 | s |
| a | 4003 | 2018-08-14T15:30:55-0400 | 2 | 9 | s |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| b | 1 | 2018-08-14T15:28:00-0400 | 3 | 2 | a |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| b | 3000 | 2018-08-14T15:33:00-0400 | 23 | 1 | o |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

where `a` and `s` were `null` in the event column when I do a left outer join `series.join(events, ["series_id", "step"], "leftouter")`

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to join the two tables by `['series_id', 'step']` and then fill the nulls.

here's an example

```py
# given the input data
data1_sdf.show()

# +---------+----+-------------------+
# |series_id|step|                 ts|
# +---------+----+-------------------+
# |        a|   1|2018-08-14 15:30:00|
# |        a|   2|2018-08-14 15:30:15|
# |        a|   3|2018-08-14 15:30:30|
# |        a|   4|2018-08-14 15:30:45|
# |        a|   5|2018-08-14 15:31:00|
# |        a|   6|2018-08-14 15:31:15|
# |        a|   7|2018-08-14 15:31:30|
# |        a|   8|2018-08-14 15:31:45|
# +---------+----+-------------------+

data2_sdf.show()

# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+
# |series_id|step|                 ts|event|
# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+
# |        a|   4|2018-08-14 15:30:45|    o|
# |        a|   8|2018-08-14 15:31:45|    w|
# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+

# join and use `first` function with current row to unbounded following
data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, ['series_id', 'step', 'ts'], 'left'). \
    withColumn('event_fnl',
               func.first('event', ignorenulls=True).over(wd.partitionBy('series_id').orderBy('step').rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize))
               ). \
    show()

# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+---------+
# |series_id|step|                 ts|event|event_fnl|
# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+---------+
# |        a|   1|2018-08-14 15:30:00| null|        o|
# |        a|   2|2018-08-14 15:30:15| null|        o|
# |        a|   3|2018-08-14 15:30:30| null|        o|
# |        a|   4|2018-08-14 15:30:45|    o|        o|
# |        a|   5|2018-08-14 15:31:00| null|        w|
# |        a|   6|2018-08-14 15:31:15| null|        w|
# |        a|   7|2018-08-14 15:31:30| null|        w|
# |        a|   8|2018-08-14 15:31:45|    w|        w|
# +---------+----+-------------------+-----+---------+
```